# Why does the following Excel MATCH function not return the 'Matched' values?

Tags: excel, match

Why does the following Excel MATCH function not return the 'Matched' values?

```
{=MATCH($A2, $C$2:$C$4,0)}
```

I have been struggling with an Excel MATCH function for a long time now.

I have created what is essentially the same MATCH function below on a much simplified data set (motor manufacturers), however even the simplified version is not working.

Please could someone help explain why.

**For reference:**

- All cells are formatted as 'Text' apart from the cell I am putting
  the formula in. I have also tried 'General' formatting.
- There are no special characters or whitespace in either the lookup
  value column or the lookup array column.
- I have entered the formula using Ctrl+Shift+Enter to create an array
  formula (I also tried without, but neither work).
- I have ordered both columns in descending (A-Z) order (even though I
  don't think I need this for match type '0' (Exact).

Below is my sample 'file'.

```
________________________________________________________________________________________
|RowNum |A Lookup Value |B MATCH Formula          |C Lookup Array |D Equal to Formula |
|1      |Text - String  |=MATCH($A2, $C$2:$C$4,0) |String         |e.g. =A6=C2        |
|-------|---------------|-------------------------|---------------|-------------------|
|2      |aston martin   |#N/A                     |ford           |TRUE               |
|3      |audi           |#N/A                     |jeep           |TRUE               |
|4      |bugatti        |#N/A                     |lotus          |TRUE               |
|5      |chevrolet      |#N/A                     |               |                   |
|6      |ford           |#N/A                     |               |                   |
|7      |infiniti       |#N/A                     |               |                   |
|8      |jeep           |#N/A                     |               |                   |
|9      |land rover     |#N/A                     |               |                   |
|10     |lexus          |#N/A                     |               |                   |
|11     |lotus          |#N/A                     |               |                   |
|12     |maserati       |#N/A                     |               |                   |
|13     |mazda          |#N/A                     |               |                   |
|14     |mclaren        |#N/A                     |               |                   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Do you have calculation set to manual?

Comment: Dear God, Rory, I feel like such an IDIOT!!!!  I will go and punish myself accordingly!!  Thank you.... <hangs head in shame>

Comment: "When you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth."

Comment: @Rory if you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Interestingly, I was trying this in a new workbook and had not modified any settings.  I have never set Calculation to manual knowingly in any workbook before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you have calculation set to manual. Since the first formula would return #N/A, when filled down, they will all return the same value.

The calculation mode for an Excel session defaults to the saved mode of the first workbook opened, so if you opened a workbook that someone had saved with manual calculation, then opened a new workbook, calculation would have been set to manual without you doing anything.

Comment: Thanks Rory, that's exactly what had happened. I have not knowingly in the last year set calculation to manual.  I did however open a workbook from someone else where calculation was set to manual....